# Como implementar um mapeamento "um para zero"?

Tags: java, hibernate

O cenário é o seguinte: Um usuário pode ter muitos ou nenhum comentário nos boletins publicados em um sistema - obviamente, um comentário pertence a um único usuário.

O problema é que o Hibernate não possui nenhuma anotação do tipo `@OneToZero` ou qualquer coisa semelhante, então como posso fazer esse mapeamento?

Do lado do usuário (classe `User`), para listar os comentários que um usuário possui fiz o seguinte:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userID", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Comment> comments;
```

Creio que o mapeamento acima esteja correto. Mas do lado dos comentários (classe `Comment`) eu não sei o que fazer para definir que um comentário pode existir da mesma maneira que ele pode nunca ser realizado.

```
// como mapear aqui? 
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user")
private User userID;
```

Eu até tentei fazer com `@ManyToOne`, mas é lançada uma `NullPointerException` sempre que tento realizar qualquer operação de CRUD com o usuário. Um simples *insert* já é suficiente para "*crashar*" a aplicação justamente porque os comentários são nulos. Mas aí que está, um usuário não possui comentários quando este é registrado no sistema.

Minhas classes estão assim:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userID", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Comment> comments;

   /* ...outros atributos... */
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne //ManyToOne gera uma NullPointerException, mas creio que esteja próximo do certo
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user")
    private User userID; 

    /* ...outros atributos... */
}
```

Comment: Se você tem uma *NullPointerException* ao gravar *Comment*, então você está gravando *Comment*! Por que você tenta gravar *Comment* sem um usuário? Uma ligação "one to zero" seria o mesmo que ligação nenhuma, então não faria sentido este tipo de ligação. Desde que você não esteja tentando gravar um *Comment* sem um *User*, as suas anotações estão corretas e deve funcionar gravar usuário sem nenhum comentário.

Comment: @Caffé magicamente funcionou hoje, quando fui testar **o mesmo** código, inclusive utilizando os mesmos métodos de *insert*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente adicionar a anotação `@NotFound` com o atributo `(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)`, ficando:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE) //Linha inserida
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user")
private User userID; 

/* ...outros atributos... */
}
```

## **Fontes:**

1. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841354/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841354/hibernate-one-to-zero-or-one-mapping)
2. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146064/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146064/bypass-entity-not-found-error-with-jpa)
3. http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-notfound-hibernate

Comment: Se não funcionar, avisa.